# How to create a facet in Sitecore Content Search (Lucene) based on Real Time Data?

Tags: indexing, lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore7.2

With Sitecore Content Search configuration is it possible to support the addition of a field which is populated with a value at search time, not index time? The population would be from an in-memory data structure for performance.

Essentially without re-indexing the values need to be updated/accessed, examples for this real time field would be Facebook Likes, In Stock, or Real Time Pricing. This data would then be used for faceting such as items with a range of Facebook likes, in-stock versus out-of-stock, or real time price facets.

Answer (score 1):

The content search api does the searching on an iindexable, so I would look into that - you'd probably have to implement this interface yourself.
More info here:

http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-search-operations-explained.aspx

If you need to search on data that is not in the index I would question whether sitecore search is the best option here. If the data needs to be searched in real time then maybe a database would suffice.

If the data set is large and you need realtime access then maybe a nosql database such as MongoDB might be the right choice. Hope this has given you some ideas and you reach a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the Sitecore dynamic index. The idea is to query your "large" index from within your **in-memory index** which you'll use dynamically. The implementation is relatively easy.

More info: http://www.sitecore.net/en-gb/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/sitecore-7-development-team/posts/2013/04/sitecore-7-dynamic-indexes.aspx

Comment: Is there a way to execute a Query Time join so the in-memory index is a subset of the data the needs to change in near real time while the larger file system index remains the same?

Comment: Open the link I mentioned and look for `var dynamicCrawler = new SitecoreFlatItemCrawler(results);this.Configuration.AddCrawler(dynamicCrawler);` Then you rebuild the in-memory index and you have your subset in memory.